# TensorFlow Import Failure: Image not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tensorflow

I'm trying to install and use TensorFlow with Python 3.6 on my Mac. I have followed all of the steps listed on the TensorFlow install site https://www.tensorflow.org/install, but after finishing with the process I get a `Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime` error when trying to import TensorFlow into my Python environment.

---

My computer is running MacOS and Python 3.6.3. I am inside an Anaconda virtual environment. I have fully gone through the installation guide (to the letter) and have tried installing from source as well as with prebuilt wheel directories.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcublas.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
  Reason: image not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcublas.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
  Reason: image not found


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I think that TensorFlow should be importing (unless I'm doing something very bad), but this error gets thrown. I suspect that the error is due to an incorrect installation, or an issue with paths, but I do not know where to start with correcting this issue. It may be a deeper problem however, so it would be greatly appreciated if anyone could shed some light on a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: `libcublas` is a cuBLAS library that is part of CUDA. Are you sure you installed (or maybe tried to compile from source) `tensorflow` and not `tensorflow-gpu`? `tensorflow` on MacOS has no GPU support.

Answer (score 0):

I think a similar Issue is solved here:
[Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime in Mac OSX](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24642)

The solution from the user [mikkokotila](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24642#issuecomment-455223575) is to use

1. a specific tensorflow version

   pip install tensorflow==1.5
2. Use conda installation

   conda install tensorflow